# Setting onclick function to <li> element

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically add onclick function to "li" tagged elements.
But the event does not fires.
Here is my code:

```
var arrSideNavButtons = [];
var sideNavLi = document.getElementsByClassName('side-nav')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'); 
var arrayOfSceneAudios = [scene1Audio, scene2Audio,...];

for (var i = 0; i < sideNavLi.length; i++) {
    sideNavLi[i].onclick = function() {
        arrayOfSceneAudios[i].play();
    }
    arrSideNavButtons.push(sideNavLi[i]);
}
```

Is it possible to code it this way?
If yes, what is my mistake?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: How do you know that the event handler is not triggered?

Comment: @Felix Kling there is console.log in the code.

Comment: Good. If you already look at the console anyway, is there an error message by any chance? If not, odds are that `sideNavLi` is an empty list. If you are certain that it's not, there is not much else we can say. You should create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `onclick` handler in a closure, else it only get assigned to the last elem in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < sideNavLi.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        sideNavLi[i].onclick = function() {
            arrayOfSceneAudios[i].play();
        }
        arrSideNavButtons.push(sideNavLi[i]);
    })(i)
}
```

Comment: Don't work for me. Did you test it before? I mean, is it problem with me or still in the for loop?

Comment: @user2998173: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820). Set breakpoints, inspect variables. We can only work with what you told us. It's on you to make sure that `sideNavLi` actually contains a set of elements. Similar for `arrayOfSceneAudios`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. 
I have console.logs every step, i just delete them here to make code shorter. The vars are ok.

Comment: You were right about setting onclick only for last element.
Also the problem was in another function which overwritten this function. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix Kling can you help me in logical part? I have setted play() function for every button, but when i click on next one, they play one over another. How i can pause it before starting play a new one?
I don't want to create a new post. Thanks!

Comment: @user2998173: You could assign the currently playing track to a variable defined outside the handler. Then inside the handler you check before whether the variables has a value and if yes, pause the track. For example (inside the handler): `if (currentTrack) { currentTrack.pause();} currentTrack = arrayOfSceneAudios[i]; currentTrack.play();`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to reuse one single function, instead of creating a new one at each iteration:

```
var arrSideNavButtons = [],
    sideNavLi = document.getElementsByClassName('side-nav')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'),
    arrayOfSceneAudios = [scene1Audio, scene2Audio,...],
    handler = function() {
        this.sceneAudio.play();
    };

for (var i = 0; i < sideNavLi.length; i++) {
    sideNavLi[i].sceneAudio = arrayOfSceneAudios[i];
    sideNavLi[i].onclick = handler;
    arrSideNavButtons.push(sideNavLi[i]);
}
```

Comment: @FelixKling Interesting link, but my answer doesn't extend the `Element` interfaces, it only adds properties to single elements. It still discomforts me a bit, and html5 `data-*` attributes containing the index `i` could be used instead, but I find this is clearer and shorter.